# It's still okay to punch Nazis, isn't it?

Tags: discussion, code-of-conduct

Okay, a bit of context here: I was engaged in discussion with some other users and the topic of Nazis came up, as it does. And I mentioned that, as far as I was concerned, the only good Nazi is a dead Nazi.

It was brought to my attention that this runs afoul of the Code of Conduct. Apparently my attitude is considered "unwelcoming to Nazis" and "bigotry against Nazis" and "condoning violence towards Nazis". Surely some hypothetical snowflake Nazi's hurt feelings aren't more important than the rest of us, is it?

See, the thing here is, I don't want to be welcoming to Nazis. At all. I don't want them chatting with users, I don't want them voting on anything, I don't want them setting site policy, or posting their opinions anywhere, I don't want them on this site, period. But if the code of conduct needs me to be "inclusive and respectful" to them, encouraging and welcoming their participation regardless of how I feel, that automatically makes it unwelcoming towards ME because I don't want to be anywhere near them. And surely that should count for something, right?

Is this really a Code of Conduct violation? Surely "a community where all people feel welcome" just means people who aren't Nazis, right? We can still "tolerate any language likely to offend or alienate people based on" being a Nazi, right? We need to be allowed to speak out against people who spew hateful doctrines, and not let them hide under a policy that was always supposed to protect people.

Comment: Are we talking *literal* punching and call to violence or "No, you don't belong here" go aways? Cause as a moderator, I totally would do the latter.

Comment: @JourneymanGeek Not like I can literally punch anyone over the Internet. I just want them to never exist anywhere that I am. Or anywhere, really.

Comment: Surely some individual snowflake anti-Nazi's hurt feelings aren't more important than the precedent that our actions set, are they? The Code of Conduct loses all meaning if you get to pick and choose the people to which it applies, the people to which you are required to be respectful towards.

Comment: What is a Nazi to you? How do you identify a Nazi? How can we discern in a network of technical Q&As whether a publication is a legitimate question or a Nazi work?

Comment: Well, not all sites are technical in nature, we have a broad array of topics

Comment: I read the whole question and am confused by the word "_still_" in the title (at revision 1). What does it mean by "_still_"? Did you say things like this before and not get called out or someone said "yeah the way you said what you said is totally in line with the CoC"?

Comment: Exactly what Cody said. What if I post the same question replacing every occurrence of "Nazis" with anything else, say, "Putin supporters", do I still get the same "privilege"? How about "Trump supporters"? Maybe "cat lovers"? You see how this is a slippery slope? Who decides which group of people can be disrespected on the platform with no consequences? As long as those people also abide by the site rule, there's little to no harm. You are free, however, not to interact with them if you feel like it's the right thing to do.

Comment: I'm confused.  How many people in their 9th decade and older visit the network who are likely to be the target of this? Isn't this a bit like dissing Visigoths or say residents of Brigadoon or Shangri-La? If you're calling someone a Nazi (Nazi-like) then that might count as a violation. Who is offended exactly? Is it those who are likely to be dubbed as  Nazi-sympathisers? Proposed solution: Auto-replace every instance of the word "Nazi" with "Nosy". This reduces the anachronism factor, confuses people, and discourages them from asking what you mean lest they be dubbed nosy.

Comment: Kind of a side note: from the sounds of it, you didn't actually *encounter* a Nazi, but merely saw someone *mention* Nazis and decided to interject your opinion about them apropos of nothing. Code of Conduct aside, I would flag such a comment as "no longer needed". While "the only good Nazi is a dead Nazi" is a sentiment I agree with, it does not suggest an improvement to a question or answer, which is what comments on Stack Exchange are supposed to be used for.

Comment: @W.O. It may shock you, but the ideology still has followers even today. Who were born *after* 1945.

Comment: Genuinely? Honestly I thought it was just used these days as a slap-back to anyone who's a bit pedantic or precise, or maybe a few nutty fringe-types scattered in remote places, but in real-life Nazis? Organised, communicating? Not even slightly funny then. @VLAZ

Comment: Just to be clear, I didn't call anyone in particular a Nazi. I was expressing my opinion of Nazis in general since that's what was being discussed.

Comment: @VLAZ well, at least they are easily recognized by their 'Parking Enforcement Officer' uniform and little electric tank.

Comment: recently related question (also related to recently new CoC): [Did my profile violate the new Code of Conduct?](/q/389751/997587)

Answer (score 10):

Well - I'd generally say calls to violence is a bad thing in *general*, as is *literal* punching. There's *sometimes* more appropriate places for it but I feel like if we're discussing nazis and violence, its generally not going to be a fun topic of conversation.

While the actual story I refer to has a lot of language that's not really SE friendly, so a cleaned up version of the important bits goes like

> "you have to nip it in the bud immediately. These guys come in and it's always a nice, polite one. And you serve them because you don't want to cause a scene. And then they become a regular and after awhile they bring a friend. And that dude is cool too.
>
> And then THEY bring friends and the friends bring friends and they stop being cool and then you realize, oh no, this is a Nazi bar now. And it's too late because they're entrenched and if you try to kick them out, they cause a PROBLEM. So you have to shut them down.

And of course all the barkeep had to say was "get out". As a mod, while I'm generally not grumpy and don't hate everyone, I do have the ownership of my spaces to do this.

So basically *actual* nazis and people who are generally the sort of people who feel our 'rules' and COC are unacceptable, and they totally *need* to have their way with these things are *unwelcome*.

No violence needed, just a gentle 'You're unwelcome here'

The problem with language like 'punching nazis' is well, some people twist it that its an actual call for violence. We're protecting our communities *first*, and *generally* we ought to be focused on protecting the members of our community. I've tended to use the analogy of sheepdogs - we're going to watch out for 'ours' first, *then* focus on deterring a chasing off predatory sorts and anything remotely aggressive comes last.

And while I don't *disagree* with the sentiment, we have better ways, and gentler ways of evicting that sort from here. There's a certain (one might say terrible) power to *calmly* telling someone they're unwelcome in a shared space where people trust you, then proceeding to (with a minimum of actual force) gradually showing them how unwelcome they are.

Comment: If I understand this correctly, you're saying it's okay to be unwelcoming to them, as long as we're not actively threatening anyone?

Comment: Quite a lot of modding is applied, careful, unwelcoming - I've literally told someone who was abusive in one of my chats that he was unwelcome. Then proceeded to suspend him, and his sock.

Answer (score 8):

First, [from our Terms of Service's section on Acceptable Use](https://stackoverflow.com/legal/acceptable-use-policy):

> Hate Content, Defamation, and Libel. Hate speech and other objectionable content that is unlawful, defamatory, and fraudulent. Note that an allegation of defamatory expression, in and of itself, does not establish defamation. The truth or falsehood of a bit of expression is a key element in establishing defamation, and we are not in a position to make that sort of fact-based judgment. That said, if we have reason to believe that a particular statement is defamatory (a court order, for example), we will remove that statement.

Bigotry and hate content are not welcome here, and I'm pretty sure that by extension, neither is support of bigotry or hate content. Flag such content for moderator attention.

You've already see [the CoC (Code of Conduct) page](/conduct) (or if you haven't, please do).

#### You can change the *way* you express your views to be OK

> [...] I mentioned that, as far as I was concerned, the only good Nazi is a dead Nazi.
>
> It was brought to my attention that this runs afoul of the Code of Conduct. Apparently my attitude is considered "unwelcoming to Nazis" and "bigotry against Nazis" and "condoning violence towards Nazis". Surely some hypothetical snowflake Nazi's hurt feelings aren't more important than the rest of us, is it?
> [...]
> We need to be allowed to speak out against people who spew hateful doctrines, and not let them hide under a policy that was always supposed to protect people.

By all means, do so! I'm with you **as long as** it's done *in a way* that doesn't violate the CoC. It's entirely possible to do so. And when that is done, those who spew hateful doctrines cannot hide behind the CoC. The CoC will be the weapon against them, and you will probably find many others rallying with you.

> Do not be overcome by evil, but overcome evil with good.

#### To address your "don't wants" (TL;DR flag bad content)

> I don't want them chatting with users

If *they* do anything in chat or in comments or in posts that violates the CoC, then flag them (probably as "rude or abusive" / "harassment, bigotry, abuse"). Then the mods will handle them appropriately. Good chance that will involve them getting a suspension- in which case, they will no longer be chatting with users.

If they do it in a post, there's also a good chance they'll get picked up by [the Charcoal team](https://charcoal-se.org/) and get put on a watch list. (if they post again, the Charcoal team will know about it).

> I don't want them voting on anything,

Voting is an earned privilege. In a sense, if they actually create content worthy to be upvoted... [mission accomplished?](https://xkcd.com/810/). Of course, if/once they do *anything* that violates the CoC, flag it and the mods will handle it. If they vote fraudulently, they'll get suspended (see [What is serial voting and how does it affect me?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/126829/997587))

> I don't want them setting site policy

Participation on Meta is also a privilege. See above point. Same goes for flagging and close-voting. If they flag things wrong (and consequently get their flags declined), they'll get temporarily suspended from flagging.

> or posting their opinions anywhere

We don't do opinions in posts on main sites. They're tolerable to a degree in comments, and I think (?) they're okay in discussions on meta sites (we're only human). Opinions are fine in chat as long as they aren't expressed in a way that violates the CoC. If a user makes an opinionated, on-topic post on a main site, then you can always downvote it. If it's a question, flag (or close-vote) it as opinion-based. If the opinion or the way it is expressed violates the CoC, flag as such (probably as "rude or abusive" / "harassment, bigotry, abuse", or if those don't work, use a custom flag reason)

> I don't want them on this site, period

TL;DR wait for them to do something bad, then flag that bad thing.

[Contacting Stack Exchange Inc. to report unacceptable behaviour or content](https://meta.stackexchange.com/contact) is also an option according to the Code of Conduct page. The CoC page also shows the steps of handling bad users: Usually they get a warning first, then a suspension, then in bad cases, the account gets expelled from the network.

> But if the code of conduct needs me to be "inclusive and respectful" to them, encouraging and welcoming their participation regardless of how I feel, that automatically makes it unwelcoming towards ME because I don't want to be anywhere near them. And surely that should count for something, right?

Most interactions with people online are optional. For example, when you first use a Stack Exchange chatroom, you get a message that includes the following: "*If a situation makes it hard to act kindly, stop participating and move on.*"

This is said alongside the points on flagging. If you see something that should be flagged, please flag it instead of ignoring it.

Again, if they haven't done anything bad yet, just ignore them, or if you're a vigilant one, check on the profile page at `?tab=activity` every so often and see if they've done anything bad yet. If they're on multiple sites, it'll probably be easier to look at their network profile instead.

Also related: [Are spammers and trolls part of the community?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/386391/997587).